# Child class properties are not being mapped to parent class properties in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I can't seem to figure out why the child class properties are not being mapped to the parent class properties. The values for the Parent class are null. Does there need to be an explicit conversion of the properties? I suspect there shouldn't be. I believe I am not using the proper XML annotation. Any help would be appreciated.

-C

Main:

```
Converter converter = new Converter(ChildClass.COSTAR);
```

Converter class

```
public Converter(ParentClass iClass)
{
    mClass = iClass;
}
```

Values from debugger:

```
mName = {java.lang.String@724}"Costar" // Child class
mRows = {java.lang.String@725}"16"     // Child class
mCols = {java.lang.String@726}"24"     // Child class
value = null                           // Parent class
columns = null                         // Parent class
rows = null                            // Parent class
```

Parent class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ParentClass", propOrder = {
"value"
})
public class ParentClass {

@XmlValue
protected String value;
@XmlAttribute
protected String columns;
@XmlAttribute
protected String rows;

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(String value) {
    this.rows = value;
}

public String getColumns() {
    return columns;
}

public void setColumns(String value) {
    this.columns = value;
}

}
```

Child class:

```
public class ChildClass
       extends ParentClass
{

public static final ChildClass COSTAR = new ChildClass("Costar", 16, 24);

public static final ChildClass LOSTAR = new ChildClass("Lostar",8,12);

public static final ChildClass JOSTAR = new ChildClass("Jostar",16,24);

@XmlValue
private String mName;
@XmlAttribute
private String mRows;
@XmlAttribute
private String mCols;

public ChildClass(String iName, int iRows, int iCols)
{
    if(iName == null)
    {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot pass in null name");
    }

    if(iRows<1)
    {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid plate row dimension: " + iRows);
    }

    if(iCols<1)
    {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid plate column dimension: " + iCols);
    }

    mName = iName;
    mRows = String.valueOf(iRows);
    mCols = String.valueOf(iCols);

}

@Override
public String getValue()
{
    return mName;
}

@Override
public void setValue(String value)
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot reset plate mName");
}

@Override
public String getRows()
{
    return mRows;
}

@Override
public void setRows(String value)
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot reset plate mRows");
}

@Override
public String getColumns()
{
    return mCols;
}

@Override
public void setColumns(String value)
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot reset plate cols");
}

}
```

**EDIT:**

When using the debugger, it does not show the Child class being casted to the Parent class. It stays as the Child class object.

Answer (score 0):

add following annotation to `ParentClass`:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({ChildClass.class})
```

Comment: I tried it but does not work. I am trying other annotations as well but nothing seems to work.

Comment: try creating jaxbcontext as follows: new JAXBContext(ParentClass.class)

Comment: The context is fine because I am using a class path that contains all the relevant classes.

Comment: it should work; see http://www.mytechnotes.biz/2012/08/jaxb-annotation-summary-crash-course.html

Comment: It's not working but thanks for your help. I used a hack by resetting the values.